# Validating input with regular expression in bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have used the example from http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html to validate the following code

```
while [[ ! $name =~ ^[a-Z][ \t][a-Z]. ]]; do

                echo "Please enter your Firstname and Surname e.g Joe Bloggs"                           # (a)Ask for NAME,TELEPHONE NUMBER,DOB #
                read name
                echo
        done
```

I am quite simply looking to ensure user enters first and second name with a space any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @CodeGnome, no `=~` is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your regex:

- You're checking for characters between `a` (lowercase) and `Z` (uppercase). This won't do what you expect, use `[A-Za-z]` to check both upper and lowercase letters.
- You're missing repeat characters; use `+` to match one or more characters.
- The end-of-match should be `$`, not `.` (which matches any single character).

Try this:

```
^[A-Za-z]+[\ \t][A-Za-z]+$
```

If you want to validate Uppercased first and last names you could use:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+[\ \t][A-Z][a-z]+$
```

But this would not work with names like `Marty McFly` that don't follow that rule.

Comment: Sorry getting these errors: line 14: syntax error in conditional expression
line 14: syntax error near `\t][A-Za-z]+$'
line 14: `       while [[ ! $name =~ ^[A-Za-z]+[ \t][A-Za-z]+$ ]]; do'

Comment: @Tricky Dicky, thanks, I forgot to add a backslash to escape the space in the regex, updated the answer.